# Is Scheduler UI possible in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I'm very new to Power BI thing so I'm not really that sure the power and capability that a Power BI can. But all I know is that Power BI is for Analytics purposes and for tabular data and so it seems that Scheduler UI inside Power BI is impossible wherein data is coming from external let's say an Excel. Am I right?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

<del>Yes, it is possible to schedule refresh for power bi service even from your desktop.</del>

<del>You have to [use a data gateway](https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2017/07/14/configuring-power-bi-gateway-data-sources-for-files-and-folders/) if you wish to maintain the file locally. Or you can use the service connectors to directly [load the file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/service-excel-workbook-files) from somewhere like Sharepoint.</del>

<del>From there, it's just setting up [scheduled refresh](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/refresh-scheduled-refresh) of the dataset.</del>

EDIT: disregard above - asker is looking for a "UI" of the refresh schedule in PowerBi.

That's a resource that currently does not exist but I imagine it could be created through the following resources of the PowerBI Rest APIs:

[Get Refresh Schedule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/datasets/getrefreshschedule)

[Get Refresh History](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/datasets/getrefreshhistory)

Comment: Nope. Not the schedule refresh but a scheduler UI. I'm going to post it to make it to make it understandable.